# Outlook Web Addin - Event handlers

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have a business requirement where there is a need to extend the functionality of outlook.
I am exploring Office Web Addins for this requirement.I have following queries.

1. I need to automatically move all incoming email to an external location.Does Office JS API provide handlers to incoming email event?
2. If it possible to define an action with Office JS API , which when triggered can loop through all the current unread emails and perform some action on each email  (like move certain emails to a certain external location )
3. Is it possible to append custom headers to a email  being composed using Outlook web add-in?

Answer (score 1):

1. No
2. You can use EWS for that
3. No.

If your code only needs to run under the Windows version of Outlook, a COM addin might be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems not possible to meet your requirements using Outlook Web Addin.

For more information, please review the following link: [Outlook Add-ins overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I would like to know if these features would be available in future? (Like event handler to incoming message)

Comment: We will feedback the problem to the relevant Team, and they will evaluate the functions. Thank you for understanding! If you have any question, or update, please feel free to let me know.